# Finding Multicollinearity between attributes using Variance Inflation Factor

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am trying to understand the multi-collinearity that might exist between different attributes/variables in a dataset typically for a regression task by using VIF. For this purpose, I am using the Boston Housing dataset.
After finding out correlated features, I am attempting to remove them and see it's effects on linear regression model performance.

The code that I have written is as follows-

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, seaborn as sns


'''
Regression Problem-
Boston Housing dataset. Target attribute- 'medv'

For details about dataset, refer to-
https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~delve/data/boston/bostonDetail.html

'''


# Read CSV data file-
boston_data = pd.read_csv("Boston_Housing.csv")

# Get dimension of dataset-
print("\nDimension/Shape of dataset- {0}\n".format(boston_data.shape))
# Dimension/Shape of dataset- (333, 15)


# Get attribute names of dataset-
print("\nAttribute names of dataset are:\n{0}\n\n".format(boston_data.columns.tolist()))
'''
Attribute names of dataset are:
['ID', 'crim', 'zn', 'indus', 'chas', 'nox', 'rm', 'age', 'dis', 'rad', 'tax', 'ptratio',
'black', 'lstat', 'medv']
'''

# Dropping 'ID' attribute from dataset-
boston_data.drop('ID', axis = 1, inplace=True)

print("\nDimension/Shape of dataset after dropping 'ID' =  {0}\n".forma(boston_data.shape))
# Dimension/Shape of dataset after dropping 'ID' =  (333, 14)


# Check for missing values-
print("\nDoes dataset have missing values? {0}\n".format(boston_data.isnull().values.any()))
# Does dataset have missing values? False


# Visualize dataset distribution using boxplots-
sns.boxplot(data=boston_data)

plt.xticks(rotation = 20)
plt.title("Boston Housing dataset distribution using boxplots")
plt.show()


# Create correlogram-

# Compute correlation matrix of dataset-
boston_data_corr = boston_data.corr()                                  

sns.heatmap(boston_data_corr)

plt.xticks(rotation = 20)
plt.title("Boston Housing dataset Correlogram")
plt.show()


# Separate dataset into features (X) and label (y)-
X = boston_data.drop('medv', axis = 1)
y = boston_data['medv']


# Create training and testing sets-
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3)

print("\nDimensions of training and testing sets are:")
print("X_train = {0}, y_train = {1}, X_test = {2} and y_test = {3}\n\n".format(X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape))
# Dimensions of training and testing sets are:
# X_train = (233, 13), y_train = (233,), X_test = (100, 13) and y_test = (100,)




# Detect Multicollinearity using VIF-
vif = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]

# Create a pandas Series to get labeled VIF for each attribute-
vif_info = pd.Series(vif, index=X.columns)

print("\nVIF calculated for each attribute in dataset are:\n{0}\n".format(vif_info.sort_values(ascending = True)))
'''
VIF calculated for each attribute in dataset are:
chas        1.131439
zn          2.554112
crim        2.649245
lstat      11.341896
indus      13.801806
rad        14.649941
dis        15.707447
age        21.929478
black      22.853979
tax        56.334001
nox        75.640420
rm         83.056962
ptratio    86.123039
dtype: float64
'''


# Removing collinear attributes/variables-
'''
We create a function to remove the collinear variables.
We choose a threshold of 5 which means if VIF is more than 5 for a particular
variable/attribute then that variable will be removed.
'''




# Linear Regression-

# First train a Linear Regression using all attributes to get a baseline score
lr_model = LinearRegression()

lr_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = lr_model.predict(X_test)

mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
r2s = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)

print("\nLinear Regression model metrics are:")
print("MSE = {0:.4f}, MAE = {1:.4f} & R2-Score = {2:.4f}\n\n".format(mse, mae, r2s))
# Linear Regression model metrics are:
# MSE = 33.7151, MAE = 3.8272 & R2-Score = 0.6831



# Training a Linear Regression using attributes whose VIF <= 5

# Attributes to use for model training using VIF-
filtered_cols = ['chas', 'zn', 'crim']

lr_model_filtered = LinearRegression()

lr_model_filtered.fit(X_train.loc[:, filtered_cols], y_train)

y_pred_filtered = lr_model_filtered.predict(X_test.loc[:, filtered_cols])

mse_f = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred_filtered)
mae_f = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred_filtered)
r2s_f = r2_score(y_test, y_pred_filtered)

print("\nLinear Regression model metrics using selected attributes are:")
print("MSE = {0:.4f}, MAE = {1:.4f} & R2-Score = {2:.4f}\n\n".format(mse_f, mae_f, r2s_f))
# Linear Regression model metrics using selected attributes are:
# MSE = 83.6148, MAE = 6.2886 & R2-Score = 0.2141

# Linear Regression model metrics using selected attributes are:
# MSE = 46.3255, MAE = 4.9335 & R2-Score = 0.5646
```

Now, according to the calculated VIF scores for the attributes, there are just 3 attributes whose VIF score <= 10 viz., 'chas', 'zn', 'crim', because in various statistical literature I read that attributes with VIF > 10 maybe removed.

If I train a linear regression model using only these 3 attributes, the Mean Absolute Error (MAE), Mean Squared Error (MSE) and R2-Score is bad and starts to improve as I keep adding more attributes.

Why is then VIF method not working by taking the 3 attributes with VIF <= 10?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Arun, Did you get to know what was the reason? why it did not work?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite an old question, but I came across this in my own search in learning to think about multicollinearity, and will answer it for the sake of others in posterity.

The VIF results for the example model do indeed imply multicollinearity between the variables, but the approach of using a single cut-off operation to remove all variables with VIF over 10 is too heavy-handed. VIF per variable is a proxy measure of the R^2 value of that particular variable represented through a linear fit using all other variables. As such, it is also strongly related to correlation, and can intuitively be thought of as an 'aggregated correlation' of sorts.

So, using the variables in Arun's example: if you imagine that the *ptratio* is correlated with *indus* and strongly correlated with *tax*, this would result in all three variables having a high VIF value, though with *ptratio* having the greatest VIF value. However, if just *ptratio* were to be removed, the multicollinearity might go away for the other two variables through that operation alone, as *indus* and *tax* might not be strongly correlated with any other variables.

Thus, the better approach to handling variables with high VIF would be to remove the worst offender first (or conversely another variable highly correlated with the worst offender if some qualitative reasoning related to the data dictates that). Then, you reevaluate the VIFs and repeat for the worst offender until you reach some satisfactory maximum VIF value (10 is just a rule of thumb, a more conservative estimate could be 5, corresponding to R^2=0.8).

What probably happened in the above example is that Arun removed too many explanatory variables through heavy-handed use of VIF, which in turn lowered the model's explanatory power. Note that overfitting might also have contributed to a difference in MSE, but that goes beyond the scope of this question.